# What other objects can I get from the context of a message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The only part I am getting confused about with discord programming is, what context? What can context actually access when you get the context from a message. In one of my cogs I have this command `test`.

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello world!")
```

What things are in `ctx`? For example if I want to access the `Message` object I would get that by `ctx.message`. I know know this by googling a bunch. What other things are in context? Is there some kind of UML diagram for this? I want to know how I can get the `guild` object, or the `member` object. Pretty much all the Discord Model's listed in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding onto Lu M's answer, as a "clunky" method of getting at an object's attributes, you can always run:

```py
print(dir(ctx)) # or replace ctx with whatever object's attributes you are trying to find

# equivalent:

print(dir(type(ctx))) # once again, replacing ctx with any other object you might try to find
```

This will return a list of every attribute an object has available to you.
However, it's always better to use documentation when available. Use this as a "last resort" or "lazy method".

Comment: Very nice answer! I didn't think about using dir() of the class.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) is for.

Comment: How do I get the `member` object from context? Because I don't see it? I want to add a the to the person who sent the message. All I see is `author` but that is of type `User`

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov authors of messages in servers automatically are member objects: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author